# Ansible how to extract parts of a string?

Tags: ansible

I am working on a project where I have to perform multiple queries to the system and the steps that follow it depend on the results of the query (there are 2 to 3 different ways each query can branch out).

The results from the queries are stored in a string variable using the register module. For instance, for one of the queries I have to check if there are multiple standby servers configured and the expected output can look like this:

```
database role   =   PRIMARY
host name       =   random_name
service name    =   service1
target list     =   server1:10201|server4:40704|server8:52125
timeout value   =   120
```

Where the only needed part is the target list and I need to extract each server (they are separated by the "|" and I wont know how many servers will be on the target list). So essentially I need a way to scan the string until it finds the word "target list" and then extract whatever comes after the "=" and before the new-line, each one of those values could be stored in an array I guess.

I don't even know where to start, anyone know any modules or how I can go about extracting the needed parts of the strings?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample playbook, only the last line with `regex_search` is relevant here. Rest is for illustration purpose. `regex_search` can be used for extracting the desired part from the text:

```
regex_search('target list\\s+=\\s+(.*)','\\1')
```

above regex would capture everything after `=` on the line containing `target list` and back-referenced using `\1`.

```
- name: Sample playbook
  connection: local
  #  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    data: "{{ lookup('env', 'x') }}"
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ data }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ data |regex_search('target list\\s+=\\s+(.*)','\\1')}}"
```

Output of the above playbook:

```
PLAY [Sample playbook] **********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

database role   =   PRIMARY
host name       =   random_name
service name    =   service1
target list     =   server1:10201|server4:40704|server8:52125
timeout value   =   120


TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

['server1:10201|server4:40704|server8:52125']


PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the data registered in the variable *results*

```yaml
    result:
      stdout_lines:
        - database role   =   PRIMARY
        - host name       =   random_name
        - service name    =   service1
        - target list     =   server1:10201|server4:40704|server8:52125
        - timeout value   =   120
```

use the attribute *stdout_lines*, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        servers: "{{ _val.split('|') }}"
      vars:
        _line: "{{ result.stdout_lines|select( 'match', '^target list.*$') }}"
        _arr: "{{ _line.0.split('=')|map('trim') }}"
        _val: "{{ _arr.1 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  servers:
  - server1:10201
  - server4:40704
  - server8:52125
```

Use [cli_parse](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/cli_parsing.html#parsing-with-the-native-parsing-engine) if you have to repeatedly parse the same structures.